# Facebook Graph Api Question?

Tags: ios4

Hi all I am implementing the facebook api in my application.I am using my custom API for that.Now what i want is to show the profile pictures of all the user who are using my application.I am only able to fetch the data of user,his profile picture,But not able to fetch the pictures of the users who are using my application.
Please help me out how to do that.The whole day i googled for it but did not find any solution.

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible via the Facebook Graph API. A possible solution would be to send the profile pictures of each user to your server, store it and then display it wherever you want to show them.

But I think this is against the TOS of the Facebook API, and if it would not be against the TOS, you might have to request permission from the user.

Check the API TOS to see if that's possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, well if it's not possible, then how even i get the pictures of my app users to load on the server as you are saying.An more over then can we get only the names of the app users.....I know that we can get the names of the friends and their images.Just let me know if you have any idea.....

Comment: My idea would be the following: A user uses your app, you retrieve his profile picture while he's using it via the Graph API and after receiving it you upload it to a directory of your server. Then you just need to create a list of that files (i.e. a JSON file) that holds the URL for each picture, download that from your App and then create an UIImageView for each profile image and display it to the user. Only problem I see is, that when a user stops using your app, you won't even notice it. Does this sound like a solution for you?